# Is there a way to assign a signature the abstract attribute after it has been instantiated?

Tags: alloy

I would like to do something similar to the following:

```
PrimSig sig = new PrimSig(sigName,parent);
sig.isAbstract = True
```

but obviously the preceding example is not possible since the isAbstract variable is declared as final. Does the Alloy API support a way of making the signature an abstract **after it has been instantiated** ?

The reason I cannot do the following :

```
PrimSig sig = new Primsig(sigName,parent,Attr.Abstract)
```

is because the signature was instantiated by parsing another module and I'm trying to emulate passing the signature through that module.

Comment: Alloy was not designed for mixing different parsed modules. So you can hack it but I am pretty confident you're going to get yourself into lots of problems.

Comment: I would add that you might want to work with the Kodkod API directly. As I recall, the Alloy API lacks the flexibility required by such "exotic uses".